# Jupyterhub deployed via docker: Connect with a samba drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, samba, jupyterhub

So I have set up a Jupyterhub deployed with docker. As described [here.](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker)

The users would like to connect to a samba share from within their notebooks. In order for this to work, I wanted to write a small bash script. The scripts asks the user for their credentials to connect to the samba share drive. So here are my questions:

1. I have to open port 445 and 139 of the notebook server container, direct them through the jupyterhub container to the system's ports 445 and 139. Where and how can I achieve this in the docker deployed Jupyterhub framework that I have?
2. I have to grant the users SYS_ADMIN and DAC_READ_SEARCH capabilities. Suppose I don't trust the users. Do you think this is a good idea? What is the worst case scenario... please scare me. :D
3. Is there a safer way like some service running in an extra container that handles the sambashare request, creates a docker volume and mounts it during the runtime of the user's container to that same user's container?